# ¿Que contiene un archivo .mat?

Tags: python

Hola soy nuevo programando en Python, y estoy trabajando en la creación de un programa que pueda leer y plotear archivos en formato ".mat".
Me podrían explicar o dar información acerca del formato, si serán matrices, serán listas, ¿o que?
Muchas gracias

Comment: matlab tal vez? imposible saberlo solo por su extension.. se puede suponer, pero no asegurarlo...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Los archivos con la extensión .mat son archivos que están en el
>   formato contenedor de datos binarios que utiliza el programa [MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab.html).
>
> La extensión fue desarrollado por Mathworks y archivos MAT se
>   clasifican como archivos de datos que incluyen variables, funciones,
>   matrices y otra información. Archivos MAT se pueden guardar en una
>   variedad de formatos, siempre y cuando los usuarios deciden guardarlos
>   en una versión que pertenece a las Preferencias de [MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab.html).
>
> Existen los llamados nivel 4 archivos MAT en matrices bidimensionales
>   y cadenas de caracteres son compatibles y también hay los archivos de
>   nivel 5 MAT que varias cosas se incluyen como las células matrices,
>   objetos, matrices numéricas multidimensionales, estructuras y matrices
>   de caracteres. Archivos MAT también son útiles cuando se trata de
>   representar audio en varios formatos como entero con signo de 16 bits,
>   8 bits entero sin signo y punto flotante de 64 bits.
>
> [Mathworks Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab.html) es el software utilizado para abrir archivos MAT. Se
>   trata de una aplicación utilizada para desarrollar algoritmo,
>   visualizar y analizar datos, así como para calcular números.

En el caso de `Python` puedes abrir el archivo .mat de esta forma:

```
import scipy.io
mat = scipy.io.loadmat('archivo.mat')
```

o usando [mat4py](https://pypi.org/project/mat4py/) de esta forma:

```
from mat4py import loadmat
data = loadmat('archivo.mat')
```

Answer (score 3):

Según tu otra publicación donde estas leyendo archivos .mat con `sio.loadmat`, el archivo es un MATLAB, puedes leer la referencia del metodo aca: 
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html